# In go, how do I make global variables

Tags: go

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("LOADED!\n")
    fmt.Print("insert y value here: ")
    inputY := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    inputY.Scan()
    inputXfunc()
}

func inputXfunc() {
    fmt.Print("insert x value here: ")
    inputX := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    inputX.Scan()
    slope()
}

func slope() {
    fmt.Println(inputX.Text())
}
```

Whenever I run this program, it says, that inputX and inputY are unidentified. How do I make this program use variables that are accessible to all of the functions? All I want to do is devide inputY by inputX then print out the result

Comment: Truly global variables don't exist in Go and you shouldn't be using them here anyway. What you need is `func slope(inputX io.Scanner)` and then when you call it in `inputXfunc()` you should pass `inputX` into it.

Comment: If you want a variable that can be accessed by all the methods in your program above without having to pass it into any of them then just declare it above main outside any method and it will be 'package scoped' which in this case is global cause you have on package `main`.

Comment: inputX io.Scanner DOES NOT WORK IN MY CODE it gives a undefined error on "io"

Comment: you have to add import "io" to use io.Scanner

Comment: already tried to import "io " to no avail.

Answer (score 7):

I'm just putting my comment as an answer... I would recommend against this however you could just declare the variable at package scope. It would look like this;

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

var inputX io.Scanner

func main() {
    fmt.Print("LOADED!\n")
    fmt.Print("insert y value here: ")
    inputY := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    inputY.Scan()
    inputXfunc()
}

func inputXfunc() {
    fmt.Print("insert x value here: ")
    inputX = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin) // get rid of assignment initilize short hand here
    inputX.Scan()
    slope()
}

func slope() {
    fmt.Println(inputX.Text())
}
```

However a better choice would be to change your method definitions to accept arguments and pass the values into them as needed. This would like like so;

```
func slope(inputX bufio.Scanner) {
        fmt.Println(inputX.Text())
    }

 slope(myInputWhichIsOfTypeIOScanner)
```

Comment: This code did not work for me at all. I am looking for a way to pass input from one section of the code to another function. Surely there is a way to do that in go.

Comment: @liam yes and it's outlined in the second example and would work fine if you understood it and applied it to your program. There was a mistake in that I had `io.Scanner` instead of `bufio.Scanner` but it's just an example. In applying it to your program it should become clear that you're not importing the `io` package and `bufio` is the thing you call `NewScanner` from.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `init()` function and make use of it in the `main.go` by using package like `godotenv` to set os's environment variables:

`global.go` file

```
package global

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

var (
    SERVER_HOST        string
    SERVER_PORT        int
)

func InitConfig() {

    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    }

    SERVER_HOST = os.Getenv("SERVER_HOST")
    SERVER_PORT, _ = strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("SERVER_PORT"))
}
```

`main.go` file

```
package main

import(
    G "path/to/config"
)

func init() {
    G.InitConfig()
}

func main() {
    G.Init()
}
```

You will still have to import "G" package in other packages to use the variables, but I think the best way to tackle global variables in Go (or any other languages) is to make use of environment variables.